# Custom Listener on Button click in ListView Item

Tags: android, listview, interface, listener, baseadapter

I have created a **Custom Listener interface** for `Button` click in **Adapter** class, i followed this **tutorial**: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/

**Adapter:**

```
        holder.btnQtyIncrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 if (customListner != null) {  
                        customListner.onButtonClickListner(position);  
                 }  

                cart = cartArrayList.get(position);
                holder.textViewQuantity.setTag(cart);

                if(cart.getQuantity() == 9) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Already reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return ;
                }
                else 
                {                                                       
                    cart.setQuantity(cart.getQuantity() + 1);
                    holder.textViewQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));

                    totalPrice = cart.getQuantity() * cart.getPrice();

                    CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).setTotal(totalPrice);
                    holder.textViewTotal.setText(cart.getTotal());
                }

            }
        });

        .....       
        return convertView;
    }
```

And I have `implemented Listener` in `Activity` like this:

```
public class CartActivity extends Activity implements customButtonListener {    
    ......

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("CartActivity-onCreate", "onCreate");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);     

        ......              

    }   


    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();   
        Log.d("CartActivity-onResume", "onResume");             
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position) {

        totalPrice = CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).getQuantity() * CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).getPrice();   
        CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).setTotal(totalPrice);

        subTotal = subTotal + totalPrice;
    }

}
```

As you can see inside **for loop** i am `setting` and `getting total` of each and every **list item**, and then calculating **subTotal** of ArrayList items...

But whenever i do tap on **btnQtyIncrease** it makes change in **total** of `list item` price, but it would not effect on `subTotal` amount

Comment: I am thinking that you are using view holder pattern for popping list. So i n your code before setting onclicklistener holder.btnQtyIncrease.setOnClickListener( you should check if holder is set or not means if(holder != null) otherwise you will be setting new clicklistener each time, you should set click listener only first time. If I missed anything post your source code and problem in detail.

Comment: try putting ` customListner.onButtonClickListner(position);` at the end of click code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change you logic in some way that *it calculates the subTotal in adapter only and then just pass the final value to interface which will simply set it in then textview*

So your code should look like:

```
holder.btnQtyIncrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cart = cartArrayList.get(position);
            holder.textViewQuantity.setTag(cart);

            if(cart.getQuantity() == 9) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Already reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return ;
            }
            else 
            {                                                       
                cart.setQuantity(cart.getQuantity() + 1);
                holder.textViewQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));

                totalPrice = cart.getQuantity() * cart.getPrice();

                CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).setTotal(totalPrice);
                holder.textViewTotal.setText(cart.getTotal());
            }

        }
        // calculate total here
         if (customListner != null) {  
                customListner.onButtonClickListner(getTotalValue());  
          }  

    });
```

Define a method `getTotalValue`  in adapter which will iterate through the array and find the subTotal value.

And then simply set it in the textView

```
@Override
public void onButtonClickListner(float subTotal ) {
        txtView.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal));
}
```

Accordingly, change the interface signature as :

```
public void onButtonClickListner(float total);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to update value in Activity when do change in Adapter class

To update data in Activity on `btnQtyIncrease` Button click. create custom event listener using interface which will trigger in Activity when any change made in Quantity.

See following example for creating custom Listener :

[How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

Comment: I went to link, but i did not get exact usage of Custom Interface.. would you like to tell me the usage of Interface and how can i use this in existing situation, you may find more code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166412/how-to-call-adapter-class-before-activity

Comment: @Sun: you want to change `subTotal `accoding to total changes on `btnQtyIncrease` Button Click?

Comment: @Sun: ok then use custom Interface as in provided link to get total change on button click in Activity then update subTotal

Comment: i am not getting exactly what to do ? How can we use interface to get that ?

Comment: @Sun: dude do it in same way as in provided example in link

Comment: like i told you I did not understand the usage of Interface, that' why i don't know How do I use that ? show me the way ...for my further learning

Comment: @Sun: create `MyListener` interface and `implements` in Activity .  send `this` to Adapter class and call ` ml.callback(this, ""+cart.getTotal());` on `btnQtyIncrease` button click by passing value