# BaseAdapter not updating value in an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, adapter, baseadapter

I am creating `Shopping Cart` application and getting Image, Name, Price, Qty and Total of each and every Item, but not getting SubTotal of all the list items for the first time, and when I call Cart activity again then getting Sub Total of all the Cart Items.

**NOTE:**
The issue is activity calls first then an adapter therefore i am not getting Total for the first time and i am setting value for the total in an adapter.

**CartActivity's** whole code check [here](http://pastebin.com/LZqUbfaB)

**CartAdapter's** whole code check [here](http://pastebin.com/xGGTthNk)

**CartArrayList.java:**

```
public class CartArrayList {

    static ArrayList<Cart> cartArraylist = new ArrayList<Cart>();

}
```

**CartActivity.java**

```
for(int d=0; d<CartArrayList.cartArraylist.size(); d++) {

Log.d("ITEM-NAME:", CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getName().toString());

Log.d("ITEM-QUANTITY:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getQuantity()));

Log.d("ITEM-PRICE:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getPrice()));

Log.d("ITEM-TOTAL:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getTotal()));

subTotal = subTotal + CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getTotal();

Log.d("SUB TOTAL:", String.valueOf(subTotal));

}

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

textSubTotal.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+decimalFormat.format(subTotal));

}
```

**CartAdapter.java:**

```
        df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");

        totalPrice = cart.getQuantity() * cart.getPrice();
        Log.d("Total:Adapter", String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).setTotal(totalPrice);
        holder.textViewTotal.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+df.format(cart.getTotal()));
```

**My Question is Why I am not getting value for :**

```
Log.d("ITEM-TOTAL:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getTotal()));
```

**Logcat**

```
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-NAME:(4176): Item 1
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-QUANTITY:(4176): 1
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-PRICE:(4176): 999.0
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-TOTAL:(4176): 0.0
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/SUB TOTAL:(4176): 0.0

11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-NAME:(4176): Item 2
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-QUANTITY:(4176): 1
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-PRICE:(4176): 1900.0
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/ITEM-TOTAL:(4176): 0.0
11-27 13:03:16.518: D/SUB TOTAL:(4176): 0.0

11-27 13:03:16.598: D/Total:Adapter(4176): 999.0
11-27 13:03:16.608: D/Total:Adapter(4176): 1900.0
```

Comment: please post whole code with adapter code

Comment: @DroidDev I have posted whole code, please check.

Comment: @Sophie where you are defininf CartArrayList.cartArraylist??

Comment: @Hardy check an updated code

Comment: Have you gone through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30253240/2591002) ?

Answer (score 0):

@Sophie you are getting total into adapter because you are doing this

```
 totalPrice = cart.getQuantity() * cart.getPrice();
    Log.d("Total:Adapter", String.valueOf(totalPrice));
    CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(position).setTotal(totalPrice);
```

--> you are **setting total** price and **then you are getting** it so first time you are **setting total value or not please check**

```
 for(int d=0; d<CartArrayList.cartArraylist.size(); d++) {

        Log.d("ITEM-NAME:", CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getName().toString());

        Log.d("ITEM-QUANTITY:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getQuantity()));

        Log.d("ITEM-PRICE:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getPrice()));

        Log.d("ITEM-TOTAL:", String.valueOf(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getTotal()));
CartArrayList.cartArraylist.setTotal((CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getQuantity())*(CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getPrice()));
        subTotal = subTotal + CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getTotal();

        Log.d("SUB TOTAL:", String.valueOf(subTotal));

    }
```

--> post your code again if it is still not working :) thanks

Comment: yes i know this is the only question how can i get value for the very first time, I have posted my whole code already

Comment: @Sophie try this code at first you will get your total there

Comment: but my concern is why I am not getting value CartArrayList.cartArraylist.get(d).getTotal()) in onCreate

Comment: @Sophie because you are not setting your value to set total at first time which you are doing in adapter.