# Refreshing previous activity

Tags: android

I know some people asked the question, but no answers helped me, and i'm new on android :)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850683/using-onresume-to-refresh-activity) could help me. But I cannot figure it out.

1. I have two Activities : Activity1 and Activity2
2. I go to Activity2 by using the button01

I want automatic refresh When I back to Activity1 using even physical back button.

Code of Activity1

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }    
        });            
    }
}
```

Code of Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);     
    }
}
```

Kind request for elaborate suggestions...
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling `startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0)` to trigger the second Activity, when that Activity finishes, your first Activity will receive the callback `onActivityResult()` regardless of what action triggered Activity2 to finish.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    /** ...The code you already wrote here... **/

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //Do your update or refresh here...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //This method also gets called every time the Activity is
        // moved into the foreground, you can call your refresh here as well.
    }
}
```

If you need to pass some data back, you can call `setResult()` in the second Activity before finishing and that data will be available in `onActivityResult()` as the `resultCode` and `intent` parameters.

This developer training article will hopefully provide further insight:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't need any result! I just want to refresh/reload the Activity1 when I back here even using physical back button. I am very new and want very simple code to refresh. Thank you again.

Comment: Then you don't have to pass anything back, the callback is still going to fire because you used `startActivityForResult()` to trigger the initial action.  You can just ignore the result parameters.  You can also use `onResume()` if you would prefer not to use this method, but `onResume()` will trigger in more cases than just when you are coming back from this second screen.

Comment: You know, I am new here and also new to onResume() method. Could you please change your above code to onResume() method? Anybody very new will be helped. Thank you again.

Comment: Edited, you can use either one.  If you choose to call `onResume()`, then there is no point in using `startActivityForResult()`, and you should replace that with `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to overide onResume and do what you need there. It should be called when your activity is first started or when it gets focus back.

See here for more: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html.