# How To Update an TextView with an HTTP response every 15 minutes?

Tags: android, json, http, android-studio

How do I run this function say every 15 minutes so it may check for a new Topic that has been added to the database.
I a very simple snippet getData() in the mainactivity that will send a HTTP request to a PHP script, then retrieve and update an TextView with the results example being a simple Topic. 
Now I would like to make this function run every 15 minutes and set the new result to TextView.

```
public void getData() {
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(""); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        topic.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        String n = "";

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        n = n + "Topic: " + json.getString("Topic") + "\n";
        topic.setText(n);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do it on onResume();? Users rarely leave an app open for longer than 15 minutes. If you must do it this way, you'll either need to set up a thread and sleep for 15 minutes or perhaps get a timestamp when you update, and in onResume() if 15mins have passed run the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question provided by Dave S.
Refreshing activity OnResume();
[Using onResume() to refresh activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850683/using-onresume-to-refresh-activity)